# Trying to remember a movie or show about a large stone egg

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

When I was a kid (born in 1979), I remember my family watching a show or movie about a large statue of an egg. The egg was being studied by someone, possibly a journalist, who took pictures of the egg regularly until it finally hatched a demon or gargoyle of some sort. I also remember it flying and chasing a man while beams shot out of its eyes. Was this real?  Does anyone else remember this?

Comment: Do you happen to remember whether the statue in the woods? In a museum? A park?

Answer (score 8):

I think you are looking for [Witches Brew (1980)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witches%27_Brew_(film))

And on [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0081763/).

As part of the plot:

> Meanwhile, Vivian Cross (Lana Turner) is controlling several of the other wives via a **sculpture of an egg** (modeled on a demonic witches' egg they find in a book on witchcraft) in which a being is hatched. This **winged creatures whose eyes shoot green flames** chases Joshua's car and nearly kills him before Vivian destroys it via her magic.

You can see the whole film here.  The bit with the egg and the laser-shooting gargoyle starts at around the 50 minute mark.